# Raster File Clipping

Tags: raster, clip

I am trying to clip a raster image with the outline shape of a country, I imported the .png image in using the georeferencer plugin. I then selected the country I wanted to use and saved it as a shapefile. I then tried to use the Raster extraction - clip raster by mask layer.

But this did not work

[image: Original .png image]

[image: Country Shapefile]

[image: Last image is what it output]

The last image is what I managed to get it to output, but on the other occasions it did not work at all and that last image is not exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making the mistake of not selecting the add alpha before running